# Is it possible to check CSV file for syntax error using JS?

Tags: javascript, csv, frontend

I have some large csv files with some syntax errors in it. On frontend I want to find a line which contains that error and display it to user in order he could fix it.

Is it possible? Could you suggest some libraries for this or may be a general idea how I can implement this on my own ?

***Example***

[image: example of wrong csv file]

Here we have an extra comma on the third line of the file. I want to display something like this "You have a syntax error on line 3 column 1".

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of what you mean. I cannot understand well your answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-validator

https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-file-validator

One of theses libraries must do the trick.